# How to specify PYD dll dependencies search paths at runtime with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, search-path, pyd

I created a Python `PYD` extension module which i can `import` fine with Python 3.9.1 when i copy all the direct and transitive dll dependencies to the same directory where the `PYD` file lies.

However, whatever i try, i fail at adding the needed search paths at runtime with the goal of not having to copy all the dependent dlls but let the module loader find them at runtime.

I tried to add them with

- `sys.path.append` but that seems to be only for python dependencies, i.e. other python modules, but not dll dependencies
- `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]` but that seems to be only for python dependencies as well
- `os.environ["PATH"]` which usually is used by [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) to locate dll dependencies (see [dll search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order))

at runtime.

I also tried launching the `py` from a console where i first manually set up the paths with `SET "path=%path%;C:\tst"` and `SET "pythonpath=%pythonpath%;C:\tst"`

but Python always throws a `"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing TestModule: The specified module could not be found."`.

I checked the `PATH` environment of *python.exe* process right before the `import` statement and it seems fine, i.e. contains all the needed search paths.

The only thing i can think of is that python is using [LoadLibraryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` to load the `PYD`.

Is it possible to define the search paths at runtime? What am i doing wrong?

For completeness sake, here's the code for the different way's i'm trying to add the paths:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\tst')
try:
    os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
    assert(False)
except:
    pass
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = r'C:\tst'
os.environ["PATH"] = r'C:\tst' + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it's (since V3.8) very simple:

[os.add_dll_directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-management):

> Add a path to the DLL search path.
>
> This search path is used when resolving dependencies for imported
> extension modules (the module itself is resolved through sys.path),
> and also by ctypes.